# ordered pair contains sets or only members?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Is this: $(\{1,2,3\} , \{4,5\})$ is a legal ordered pair? I mean , can ordered pair contain 2 sets and not just 2 numbers?

Comment: In fact, an ordered pair can itself be the member of a set.

Comment: A legal ordered pair is $(a,b)$, where $a,b$ could be (almost) anything: numbers, sets, functions, relations, vectors, a set and a number, and so on.

Comment: Also, the elements of the ordered pair don't even need to be of the same type. A typical example would be the integers along with the addition operation: $(\mathbb Z, +)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [In mathematics, an ordered pair (a, b) is a pair of *mathematical* ***objects***...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair)

Comment: The entries of an ordered pair can even be other ordered pairs